# Play same sound effect multiple times when others are not finished yet

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I use cocos2d-x 3.0 on Windows, but the game should be on Android and iOS.

I want to create coin collection sound. My player can collect for example 10 coins with 0.1 seconds delay. Now I want to play the same effect 10 times with the same delay, whereas my effect length is 1 second. SimpleAudioEngine does not play that. How I can achieve that?

In other words I want to play the same sound with multiple streams. Please help me.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. I have plenty of sounds that are 1 second long and they are played just fine with `platEffect()`

Comment: What size are they? What format? What platform, please?

Comment: .mp3, very small in file size (like 100k) OSX, ios, Android.

Comment: I have noticed that if file is about 30Kb small, it can manage to play multiple times, but if it is about 250Kb, then it plays sequentially. BTW I use `.wav`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Size matters. If the size of .wav file is "enough" small, then it can play multiple times.